# Google Analytic not required

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a new website and trying to add Google Analytic stumbled upon Google Tag Manager. Looks like based on what I am seeing there I don't need to create Google Analytic account at all. Am I right or I am missing something?

Comment: If you want Google Analytics, you're gunna have to create an account for Google Analytics. The data (no matter how its sent) has to go somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

GTM is just a tag manager. A tag manager outputs tags based on rules and data layers and stuff. GTM has tight integration w/ GA (as opposed to just outputting the code in a generic container) since it's a google product. But GTM is separate from GA. You still need to create a GA account and specify that acct # in GTM. All GTM does is output the GA code. GTM does not collect the data or provide reports. That's what GA is for.